# SharedPreferences/Variables not read in order

Tags: android

I have my code below on the `onCreate` of my `Activity`.

```
SharedPreferences globalPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean hasFinishedIntroduction = globalPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_FINISHED_INTRO), false);

Log.d(TAG, "Has finished introduction: " + hasFinishedIntroduction);

if(!hasFinishedIntroduction){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IntroductionActivity.class));
    finish();
}

boolean hasLoggedInUsingFacebook = globalPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_LOGGED_IN_FACEBOOK), false);
boolean hasLoggedInUsingGoogle = globalPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_LOGGED_IN_GOOGLE), false);

Log.d(TAG, "Has logged in using Facebook: " + hasLoggedInUsingFacebook);
Log.d(TAG, "Has logged in using Google: " + hasLoggedInUsingGoogle);

if(!hasLoggedInUsingFacebook && !hasLoggedInUsingGoogle){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SocialLoginActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

My problem is that, every time I run my app (clean install), my app starts my `SocialLoginActivity` that is supposed to be checked second. My first check was ignored (`hasFinishedIntroduction`).
Of course I tried debugging it with `Log` messages but all works fine (the values at least).

```
10-06 03:15:09.907 12969-12969/com.sample.foo D/Bar: Has finished introduction: false
10-06 03:15:09.937 12969-12969/com.sample.foo D/Bar: Has logged in using Facebook: false
10-06 03:15:09.937 12969-12969/com.sample.foo D/Bar: Has logged in using Google: false
```

Clearly, the app can read the `false` in the `hasFinishedIntroduction` but it ignores it and refuses to execute what's inside my first `if` statement.
What's surprising is that after I log in on my app, the user will be brought back to this `Activity` and then now, my check of `hasFinishedIntroduction`'s value will be executed and will start the `Activity` I instructed it to start.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**
I forgot to note here that I have also put some `Log.d()`s in the `onCreate` of my `IntroductionActivity` and `SocialLoginActivity` but it really shows that it doesn't really call `IntroductionActivity` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u need to return from the method in the `hasFinishedIntroduction` block because the code after the block is getting executed and `SociaLoginActivity` is being launched on top of the `IntroductionActivity`.

try this:

```
if(!hasFinishedIntroduction){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IntroductionActivity.class));
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't worked for me. I forgot to note that I have also put `Log.d()`'s on my other `Activities` to figure out if they were called or not but it really goes straight to my `SocialLoginActivity`.

Comment: Can you put log inside the if code block for `hasFinishedIntroduction ` and see if it is getting executed. Also you may try pressing back once u see 'SociaLoginActivity' and see if the  `IntroductionActivity ` is there in the backstack

Comment: Oh I haven't tried that earlier. It seems that it goes in the `if` block (it prints my debug message) but never starts my `IntroductionActivity` and goes out of that `if` block and do the other `if` instead. What puzzles me is the fact that it executes that `startActivity()` to the `IntroductionActivity` after going in my `SocialLoginActivity` and go back to this `Activity` the second time.

Comment: How do you know that it executes `startActivity()` to the `IntroductionActivity` after going in `SocialLoginActivity` because the 'startActivity()' will start the activity asynchronously in the sense that main thread should not get blocked until the activity is completely launched (with all the lifecycle methods). The `startActivity()` method returns immediately but it schedules the activity to be launched. Also can you tell me what happens if put the return in the `hasFinishedIntroduction ` code block?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the error. Looks like this solution works for me. Thanks! You saved me! Looks like `IntroductionActivity`'s `onCreate` is never called because my `Activity` ignores `finish()` and goes straight starting my `SocialLoginActivity`, making `IntroductionActivity`'s state in `onPause` hence not calling `onCreate` anymore. Thank you!